# How to create a generic instanceof function that returns the object if it's an instance of that type?

Tags: typescript, types, instanceof

I'm basically trying to write a function like this:

```
function isInstance<T>(s: T): T | boolean {
  return (s instanceof T) && s;
}
```

Where if it is the instance, it returns the value as that type, and otherwise returns false.

However, when I try to compile this, I get the following error:

`'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

However, I'm a bit confused, because I am want to know if it of that type, so I feel like it makes sense to pass a `T` there. I think the issue is because TypeScript types don't exist at runtime, so this won't work, but I'm not sure of an alternative that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Was googling around and found this. Not sure how it works exactly but it seems to work?

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function isInstance<T>(s: any, t: Constructor<T>) {
  return s instanceof t && s;
}
```

Comment: It's a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures); you might want to [edit] your answer to have doc links, unless you'd like to see someone else write up an answer.